# Run MySQL query on command line from a script

Tags: mysql, bash

How can i run a mysql query from a script via the ubuntu command line using the mysql client? I know i can use the following command:

```
mysql -uroot -psecret -e "select * ..."
```

But my query is too big and would like to be read from a script instead. I tried the following and did not work:

```
mysql -uroot -psecret < /path/to/script.sql
```

i get the error:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
```

Comment: You need to specify the database name: `mysql -uroot -psecret yourDatabaseName < /path/to/script.sql`

Comment: The other way is to add `use xxxx;` inside of your script.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the database name

mysql -D yourdbname -uroot -pYourpassword < /path/to/script.sql

-D, --database=name Database to use.

-p, --password[=name] Password to use when connecting to server.
-h, --host=name     Connect to host.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way you should try.

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=your_username --password=your_password  -e "script.sql"
```

Comment: I think Tim Biegeleisen  solution also works